# Seeking guidance regarding course selection

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, beginner, coursera

I have completed Prof. Andrew Ng's **Machine Learning Specialization** a week ago and now exploring different competitions (Titanic, House Price Prediction, and from the Playground Series). I want to learn more about deep learning and different neural network architectures. So should I proceed with the **Deep Learning Specialization** by Prof.Ng or go with **Tensorflow Developer Professional Certificate** by Prof. Moroney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have completed all three so can suggest on this. after completing ML specialization Deep Learning Specialization Deep Learning specialization is better path to explore first because it has some foundation knowledge also for DL models and everything in this course is in Tensorflow so you will be covering many of the knowledge of  tensorflow also; taking "Tensorflow Developer Professional Certificate" after that will be easy and fast paced. However you can Jump directly to Tensorflow with Prof. Moroney if your goal is to start doing some experiment in tensorflow quickly.